# Handling org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException

Tags: spring-security, cas

Our spring boot web application uses CAS authentication.  We are undergoing a security scan and one of the test cases issued a log in with an invalid CAS ticket.  The test case was: "/Logon?blockbanner=true&ticket=ST-3582-f3sADdmKlq"

Since this ticket is not valid, CAS produced a warning (see below) and the result is Http 500 which the security team failed us on.

I attempted to capture this string in our spring security configuration:

```
 .regexMatchers(".+blockbanner=true.+").denyAll()
```

However, if we log in normally and a valid ticket is returned, we cannot get inside the application!!!

Is there a way to capture and handle the warning from CAS so that we can produce a better Http error such as Http 401, etc.?  Thank you!

CAS warning

```
020-04-17 11:22:26,913 WARN  o.j.c.c.v.Saml11TicketValidationFilter[AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:189] doFilter: org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: org.opensaml.SAMLException: ticket 'ST-155-g1lYXqTfB0xAOAp2RrU7-tecs_cas_sat' not recognized
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: org.opensaml.SAMLException: ticket 'ST-155-g1lYXqTfB0xAOAp2RrU7-tecs_cas_sat' not recognized
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator.parseResponseFromServer(Saml11TicketValidator.java:115)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:217)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution to this.  I added the line:

**filter.setExceptionOnValidationFailure(false);**

so that CAS does not generate warning when it gets an invalid ticket.
So, instead of Http 500, it returned Http 403 which passed the security scan test.

```
Saml11TicketValidationFilter filter = new Saml11TicketValidationFilter();
             beanFactory.autowireBean(filter);

             filter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
             filter.setRedirectAfterValidation(true);
             filter.setArtifactParameterName("ticket");
             filter.setServerName(serverName);
             filter.setExceptionOnValidationFailure(false);
```